# How to ignore a false value for `or` in `if` statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, split

I have a line like:

```
if message.content.lower().startswith("input ") and (((len(message.content.lower().split(' ')[1]) == 6) or (len(message.content.lower().split('#')[1]) == 6))):
```

Because I am reading the user's input after a space, but sometimes the user inputs a hashtag symbol, and sometimes not (but there's always a space). If the user types in a hashtag it is fine, but if the user doesn't, I get an error `IndexError: list index out of range` I'm assuming because if the user doesn't type a hashtag, nothing gets split so there's only one element in the list so `[1]` is not a valid element in the list. However, that's why I put an `or` thing, so it can check either or. But I guess Python reads the statement from left to right, so depending on how I switch the two statements around the `or` or how the user types it, I will always get a list index error. How can I stop this?

Comment: can you provide a sample input?

Comment: "but there's always a space" ... on user input? Make no assumptions about user input! You are better off writing several lines of code with intermediate variables. length checking and etc... than trying to put it all on one line.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license). If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395)?

Answer (score 1):

First do a check if the "message" has '#
' in it, then you can proceed with [splitting the string](https://pythonexamples.org/python-split-string/).
Or
store the split of "message" with # in an array, and then check the size of array to be atleast 2 as you are accessing the second element of array

Answer (score 1):

What about a

```
 try:
    if (len(message.content.lower().split(' ')[1]) == 6:
         do something
 Except IndexError:
     len(message.content.lower().split('#')[1]) == 6
```

I would need more information to write you a full answer, but that's the concept.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) which just looks for and picks out the digits.

http://pythex.org/ is good to test out the expressions before implementing them.

```
import re

m = re.search('\d', message.content.lower())
m.group(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

User a regular expression:

```
import re
if (re.match("^input #?.{6}$", message.content.lower()) != None):
```

Comment: The sample you provided in the comments was "input 1234567" and I think you mean "input 123456". right?